# How can I check if a value exists in Map in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It looks a very easy question but I haven't found it anywhere.

How can I know If a value exists in a `Map`?

For example:

```
A = [1,2,3,5,6,7]
var myMap = new Map();
for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    myMap.set(i,A[i]);
}
for (let z = 1; z < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; z++) {
    console.log(z);
    if(!myMap.hasValue(z)){
        return z;
    }
}
```

I want to check if, given one value, this value is on the hash. Like a `hasValue`.

Comment: It looks like you're using the wrong data structure. Use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead. `var mySet = new Set(A);`

Comment: @4castle why would using a Set help?

Comment: @bugs If you look at their code, their map is just a logical recreation of the array it's created from. They need to make the values be the keys.

Comment: Well, sure, but I'd imagine this is just a simplified example of a more complex problem. If it isn't, of course you're right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use iterate over the map, look for the value and return true (exiting the loop) as soon as you find it. Or you return false if the element does not exist. Something like:

```
const findInMap = (map, val) => {
  for (let [k, v] of map) {
    if (v === val) { 
      return true; 
    }
  }  
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `for (let v of map.values())`

Answer (score 30):

You cannot, other than by searching through it:

```
myMap.values().some(v => v === val) // https://tc39.es/proposal-iterator-helpers
Array.from(myMap.values()).includes(val)
new Set(myMap.values()).has(val)
```

Use an appropriate data structure instead of the `Map`, like a set of all the values, in the first place:

```
A = [1,2,3,5,6,7]
var myValues = new Set(A);

for (let z = 1; z < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; z++) {
    console.log(z);
    if(!myValues.has(z)) {
        return z;
    }
}
```

Of course, given the fact that your `A` is sorted already, you could iterate it directly to find the lowest missing value.

Comment: If it's sorted, you should not iterate, you should binary-search it - it will be much faster.

Comment: @VitaliyLebedev No, I really meant iterate here, since the code is looking for the lowest integer that is not in the array. Binary search doesn't help since we don't know which value we are looking for - you just need to iterate the integers and the array like in a merge until you find one that is missing.

Comment: Nice I use: [...map.values()].includes("value")

Comment: @JohanHoeksma That's just weirder syntax for the same as `Array.from` does :-) But there's better way nowadays

Comment: @Bergi sonwhat is a better way?

Comment: @JohanHoeksma see the edit i just made

Answer (score 11):

For me it works:

```
Object.values(myMap).includes(myValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I, personally prefers to `find`, `indexOf` and `findIndex`.

```
const array1 = (map, val) => {
  var foo;
  array2.find( (x) => foo = x === foo.id )
  return foo;
}
```

[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is already answered, but I would like to point out a way to do this without (explicitly) iterating of the entries. You can do

```
let myMap = new Map([[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 6], [5, 7]])

for (let z = 1; z < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; ++z) {
    console.log(z);
    if([...myMap.values()].includes(z) === false){
        return z;
    }
}
```

So, you could create a function

```
const mapContainsElement = (map, val) => [...map.values()].includes(v)
```